# Updating objects in LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I am trying to do an update in Linq.

```
public myFunc(MyItem newItem)
{
  using(var db = new myDataContext())
  {
     var item = (from o in db.myTable where o.id == myId select o).First();
     item = newItem;
     db.SubmitAllChanges();
  }
}
```

This doesn't update the object, I guess item = newItem changes item to refer to the other. If I change the individual fields (item.Name = newItem.Name etc.) te change is reflected, however I don't want to spread the contents of the MyItem class into multiple places to reduce maintainability. Is there some way to make the item=newItem copy on a field by field basis?

Also MyItem has a relationship to another table, and I want to update the subordinate items from newItem into item too. (FWIW, there are no adds or deletes, just updates.) Is there a standardized process for doing this?

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, `MyItem` should be a partial class - so you could add a `CopyPropertiesFrom` method to `MyItem`, and then write

```
item.CopyPropertiesFrom(newItem);
```

instead of your current assignment.

By the way, you might want to consider using this instead of your current query:

```
var item = db.myTable.First(o => o.id == myId);
```

Just makes things a bit simpler than a query expression in this case :)

Comment: It seems to me that this is a really common process. Isn't there an automatic way to do this?

BTW, great tip on the LINQ query. I do this sort of thing all the time and yours is so much more concise. undoubtedly your suggestion will significantly impact the way I write code... so thanks.

Comment: @Mike: I don't think it's *particularly* common. Normally if you want to update an entity wholesale, you'd fetch it first, edit it, then reattach.

Comment: That is an interesting comment, I thought about it in the context of my code. Why I have to do it is that the item is edited in JavaScript on the client side, then submitted as a JSON. The JSON is decoded and that object is the "newItem" in my example.

Is there perhaps a better approach to this?

Comment: @Mike: In that case you might just want to change how you decode the JSON, if possible: fetch the item, then decode the JSON "into" the existing item. It depends on how you're dealing with the JSON though.

Answer (score 4):

You can't just assign `newItem` to `item`. When you assign `newItem` to `item`, it simply points item to a new location in memory...it doesn't actually update anything on the entity.

You need to go through and assign each property individually:

```
using(var db = new myDataContext())
{
    var item = db.myTable.First(o => o.id == myId);
    item.Prop1 = newItem.Prop1;
    item.Prop2 = newItem.Prop2;
    // etc
}
```

A better option would be to extend the partial class (as mentioned by Jon Skeet) from the Entity Model and make this a method (so you can re-use the code).

Answer (score 2):

I think you should gain some understanding of basic concepts of C# variables and references first.

Types in C# are divided into two groups: **reference types** and **value types**. They are different in many aspects, and copying and comparing is one of these aspects.

Value types include simple types like `int` (watch out: `string` is not a value type though you might think so), enumerations and structures. They get copied when you reassign values to different variables, pass them as parameters etc.

By saying

```
int x = 5;
int y = 7;
x = y;
```

**You assign the value** of `y` to `x`, which results in `x` being equal to `7`.
However, if you change `y` further, `x` won't get updated:

```
int x = 5;
int y = 7;
x = y; // 7
y = 10; // x is still 7
```

On the contrary, **reference types don't get copied on assignment**. It's only references that get copied.

```
MyItem john = new Customer("John");
MyItem jack = new Customer("Jack");
jack = john; // now both references point to the same Customer
```

In this code snippet we *forgot* about `Customer` called `"Jack"` and both `jack` and `john` now point to the same object with name `"John"`.

Therefore, by saying

```
item = newItem;
```

you only make `item` point to the object referenced by `newItem` at that moment (or null if it was empty).

You might want to define an `Assign` method in your class that performs the routine of assignment:

```
public void Assign(MyItem that)
{
    this.Name = that.Name;
    this.City = that.City;

    // etc
}
```

At some point, you might also want to write an extension method that uses reflection to assign all public properties—but that's a good topic for a different question (which most likely has already been asked and answered several times).

Answer (score 0):

give it the same key and do an attach followed by a submitchanges....

Comment: I tried to do an attach, viz:

    db.myTable.Attach(newItem);

However this gives a duplicate key error. Do I have to delete the item first? That seems a little backward?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative option would be to use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) to automatically copy the values for 
you.

Above said, in many cases a simple method in a partial class would do just well (like in Jon Skeet answer).